# To report or not to report?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

(Lame title I know, but I couldn't think one that suited this more... sorry)

In the low quality posts review queue, I see quite a few posts like:

> We had some good discussion here.

or

> See also this question.

or

> See my answer to this question.

and they would all be linked to either someone else's question/answer or an answer they posted on a different question.

So with that I decide to run [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/193383?opt.textResults=true) query to see how many other answers that might match what I have seen in the low quality queue.

The query that I ran was:

```
SELECT id, CreationDate
FROM Posts
WHERE LEN(BODY) < 150
AND BODY like '%http://stackoverflow.com/questions/%'
ORDER BY CreationDate ASC
```

and it returned `1637` matches.
I put the body length to less than 150 characters* because like the examples above, most posts pointing others to another question/answer will be fairly short.

My question is, should I go through **all** those posts and report the ones that should be removed/marked as duplicate, go through and **only** focus on the more recent ones, is it ultimately up to me what I do, or would there be a better way to deal with it, or it's not really a problem at all?

*I know 150 characters wouldn't catch all the cases of it happening, but it was the first number that came to my head to check and can easily be changed.

Comment: I'd advise you to use the low quality queue as much as you like, but perhaps focus your energies on the close vote queue if you've run out of low quality things to review. It needs a lot of work, and you can filter by close reason if you like.

Comment: Like you say, it's ultimately up to you whether you think it's worth your time. I've flagged/vtc'd the occasional 2011 post but I doubt it's of much benefit to anyone; so whilst I'll review posts from years ago if they come up in the queues I wouldn't bother going searching for them. IMO moderation time on SO is best spent on the posts you come across organically.

Comment: The bad questions that need the most attention are imho those that are most likely to be looked at by someone else. If no one will ever look at that question/answer, then its not as important to handle.